# How can I return elements of an array in a numbered string?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have `array=[a, b, c, d]` and I want to return the elements in a numbered string like `"1. a, 2. b, 3. c, 4. d"`

I have tried using a `for` loop using the index `i` to return `"i. array[i]"`, but I only get the first element of the array returned, not the whole array.

```
const array = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    return `The order is currently: ${i+1}. ${array[i]}, `
}
```

I expect the output to be `"The order is currently 1. a, 2. b, 3. c, 4. d"`, but the actual output is `"1. a,"`

Comment: I meant that the actual output is "The order is currently 1. a,"

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) with a template literal and join the results.

> The map() method creates a new array with the results of calling a
>   provided function on every element in the calling array.

The map creates an array of `['1. a', '2. b', etc...]`, which produces the requested string when joined.

```js
const array = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

const result = array.map((c, i) => `${i + 1}. ${c}`).join(', ')

console.log(`The order is currently: ${result}`)
```

**How can you fix your work?**

You need to accumulate the results on each iteration, and remove the last character (the redundant `,`):

```js
const array = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

let result = 'The order is currently:'

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  result = `${result} ${i+1}. ${array[i]},`
}

console.log(result.slice(0, -1))
```

Comment: Mapping worked! Can you translate what's going on in that statement, or point me to good references about mapping syntax? Thanks a million!

Answer (score 1):

You could map the wanted parts and join the items with a comma.

```js
const array = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

console.log(`The order is currently: ${array.map((v, i) => `${i + 1}. ${v}`).join(', ')}`);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution is to use [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) starting with an **accumulator** equal to the string `"The order is currently: "` and adding the related text on each iteration. Of course, you will need some post-processing to delete the latest unwanted `comma`.

```js
const array = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];

let res = array.reduce(
    (str, v, i) => str += `${i+1}. ${v}, `,
    "The order is currently: "
)

console.log(res.slice(0, -2));
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the return inside the for statement will throw the first element in the array. Try to concat a string and then return the string.

Like this:

```
const array = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
let output = "";
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    output = output  + (i+1) + '. ' + array[i] + ', ';
}
console.log('The order is currently: ' + output);
```